# Error: "Request failed with status code 500" while posting to API firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Error: "Request failed with status code 500" while posting to API
Until here i was getting cross origin error now when i added app.use(cors()) getting internal error 500
Made the below things to my code

```
  const express=require('express')
    const app=express();
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        next();
      });
    app.use(cors());

   app.post("/project",(req,res)=>cors(req,res,()=>{
    const newProject={
        title:req.body.title,
        description:req.body.description,
        status:req.body.status,
        startdate:req.body.startdate,
        enddate:req.body.enddate,
        supervisor:req.body.supervisor,
        createdAt:admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
    }
    admin.firestore().collection("Projects")
    .add(newProject)
    .then(doc=>{
        return res.json({message:`Project ${doc.id} created successfully`})
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        res.status(500).json({error:`Something went wrong, ${err}`})
    })
}))
```

Below is the client side code :

```
const newProject=JSON.stringify({
    title:project.name,
    description:"",
    status:project.status,
    startdate:project.startdate,
    enddate:project.enddate,
    supervisor:project.supervisor,
})
axios.post("https://us-central1-flair-d7b59.cloudfunctions.net/api/project",newProject)
.then(res=>{
  this.setState({ open: false });
  Swal.fire({
    icon:"success",
    toast:true,
    title: res,
    position: 'top-end',
    showConfirmButton: false,

    showClass: {
      popup: ''
    },
    timer: 2500
  })
})
.catch(err=>{
  console.log(err)
  this.setState({loading:false})
  Swal.fire({
    icon:"error",
    toast:true, 
    title:"Something went wrong, Please try again",
    position: 'top-end',
    showConfirmButton: false,

    showClass: {
      popup: ''
    },
    timer: 2500
  })
})
```

tried a lot but no solution. Thank you

Comment: post more details *_* how can anyone know what's happening

Comment: hello @RenaldoBalaj made the code available please review it

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend making use of the [`cors`](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) middleware to handle CORS handshaking rather than do it manually.

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    next();
  });
```

to

```js
app.use(cors());
```

You also don't parse the request's body as JSON before trying to use it. This can be achieved using the [`body-parser`](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html) middleware. Because you are responding in JSON, I also assume you are sending your data as JSON.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const jsonBodyParser = require('body-parser').json();

admin.initializeApp();

const app = express();

app.use(cors()); // enable all origins

app.post("/project", (req,res) => {
  jsonBodyParser(req, res, (err) => { // parse body as JSON
    if (err) { // don't forget to handle errors when chaining to `next()` manually
      res.status(500).json({error:'Failed to parse body as JSON'});
      return;
    }

    const newProject= {
      title: req.body.title,
      description: req.body.description,
      status: req.body.status,
      startdate: req.body.startdate,
      enddate: req.body.enddate,
      supervisor: req.body.supervisor,
      createdAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
    }

    admin.firestore().collection("Projects")
      .add(newProject)
      .then(doc => {
        return res.json({message:`Project ${doc.id} created successfully`})
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({error:`Something went wrong, ${err}`})
      });
  });
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: yeah i used but no result

Comment: You have lots of repeated code. I'll refactor it, just give me a few minutes.

Comment: getting cross-origin exception  (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

Comment: Redeploy your function and retest. Also, on your client, don't stringify the data before passing it to axios, just pass the object in raw.